# Outline font installation in self-contained tree

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, truetype, environment-variables

I'd like to achieve the following: a user should be able to grab a copy of a given directory, place that anywhere in his home directory, and run `make` to build LaTeX documents in that tree *without modifying his own configuration.* The documents in that tree depend on custom truetype fonts, and the provider of these fonts suggests using `updmap-sys` to install these. But requiring users to install these fonts system-wide is unacceptable, and even having to install them locally should be avoided.

The best I could find so far are the following rules, added to my `Makefile`:

```
export TEXMFHOME=$(CURDIR)/texmf
export TEXINPUTS=$(CURDIR)/styles:$(CURDIR)/texmf:

texmf/web2c/updmap.cnf: texmf/fonts/map/dvips/tumhelv/tumhelv.map
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo -n "" > $@
    updmap --cnffile $(TEXMFHOME)/web2c/updmap.cnf \
        --dvipdfmxoutputdir $(TEXMFHOME)/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap \
        --dvipsoutputdir $(TEXMFHOME)/fonts/map/dvips/updmap \
        --pdftexoutputdir $(TEXMFHOME)/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap \
        --pxdvioutputdir $(TEXMFHOME)/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap \
        --setoption dvipsPreferOutline=true \
        --setoption pdftexDownloadBase14=true \
        --enable Map=customFont.map
```

This apparently does install the fonts in the `texmf` subtree of the directory where my `Makefile` resides. I haven't even begun checking whether the font is actually available, because suddenly my `pdflatex` starts using bitmap font instead of outline fonts. I added the two `--setoption` lines above, copied from the `updmap.cnf` of my main TeXlive `texmf` tree, but they changed nothing.

I also noticed that `updmap` will create a file `~/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log` (on OS X), but I guess a single additional environment variable should take care of that.

How can I use environment variables to install a font without modifying the user's configuration, and still use outline fonts in my PDF files?

Comment: Well if you call updmap you will (ove)rwrite map-files and so change  the configuration of the users - and you will disable the working of updmap-sys and so actually confuse the configuration of quite a number of users.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found an answer to this problem. The most useful resource to this was [*Font installation the shallow way*](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/33/04.pdf) by Siep Kroonenberg (which is also available as a [TUGboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-1/tb86kroonenberg-fonts.pdf)).

That article describes how you can simply drop font related files into the current directory, and use `\pdfmapfile{=myFont.map}` to *add* a single map file to the list of map files used by `pdflatex`. No call to `updmap` involved. The article also goes to some lengths about how to obtain metric files (`*.tfm`) and map files, but since both of these were provided in my case, `\pdfmapfile` was the most useful hint there.

Now in my case, I wanted files in a separate `texmf` tree instead of the current directory. In the end, I had to override five different environment variables to achieve this goal:

```
export TEXINPUTS=$(CURDIR)/styles:$(CURDIR)/texmf//:
export TFMFONTS=$(CURDIR)/texmf/fonts/tfm//:
export TEXFONTMAPS=$(CURDIR)/texmf/fonts/map//:
export TTFONTS=$(CURDIR)/texmf/fonts/truetype//:
export ENCFONTS=$(CURDIR)/texmf/fonts/enc//:
```

Looking at the `texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` file of my TeXlive distribution (see `kpsewhich --all texmf.cnf` to find yours), as well as the output of `pdflatex -kpathsea-debug=-1` (also read about [Kpathsea debugging](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Debugging)), was extremely helpful in figuring out which settings to override. Notice the [colon](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Default-expansion) at the end of each variable, which means prepending the stated value to the default value. Also note the [double slashes](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Subdirectory-expansion), which means recursively searching the whole tree. So far this `texmf` tree is small enough that I don't bother maintaining a `ls-R` database for it. If I did, I'd probably have to export `TEXMFDBS` as well.